# cant use [routerLink] inside the component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular, angular2-routing

Im have 2 `<router-outlet>` and everything is ok,this my `RouteConfig` inside the profile component:

```
@Component({
    selector : "profile",
    templateUrl: '/client/tmpl/profile.html',
    directives: [ ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
})

@RouteConfig([
     {name: 'Home', component: homeProfile ,path: '/' ,useAsDefault:true},
     {name: 'Credit', component: credit ,path: '/credit' },
     {name: 'BuyCredit', component: buyCredit ,path: '/buycredit' }
])
```

my problem is when I want use [routerLink] inside the `credit` component throw an Error:
"credit" has no route config. in [null]

and this is my `credit` Component :

```
import {ROUTER_DIRECTIVES,RouteConfig} from 'angular2/router';
 @Component({
    selector : "credit",
    templateUrl : "client/tmpl/profile/credit.html",
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]

})
```

template :

```
<ul>
                                 <li><a  [routerLink]="['Profile' , 'Home']"  href="#">home</a> </li>
</ul>
```

why i should use RouteConfig inside `credit` Component?and how to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```ts
<a [routerLink]="['/Profile' , 'Home']"  href="#">home</a>
```

---

As I see, you have defined `Profile` route in the Main Component and then `Profile` has child Components ie: `Home`.

So, exception occurs because:

- `Profile` in the routerLink means look for the route in this component's routeConfig.
- but you need to do `/Profile` in routerLink to tell it to look for `Profile` route in the root(Main Component)'s routeConfig