# Linking from one component to another within an router-outlet in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

How can I route from one component to another within an router-outlet in angular 2?

login.component.html

```
... login form ...
<a (click)="gotoSignup()">gotosignup</a>
<a routerlink="signup">singup</a>
<a routerlink="/signup">/singup</a>
<a routerlink="/signup/">singup</a>
<a routerlink="['signup']">[singup]</a>
<a routerlink="[/signup]">[/singup]</a>
```

login.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, Headers} from '@angular/http';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(public router: Router) {}

    gotoSignup() {
      this.router.navigate(["signup"]);
    }

}
```

In the sample above gotosignup is working thereas the router Link is not working.

Trying to use `<a [routerLink] ...` ist not working eiter. It results in the following error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'routerlink' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("
            <div class="well clearfix" style="font-size: larger;">
              <a [ERROR ->][routerlink]="['/signup']">
```

There are similar questions however they are not working for me. The seem to refer to pre alpa versions of angular 2 eg.:

- [cant use [routerLink] inside the component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361254/cant-use-routerlink-inside-the-component) < most similar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add `imports: [RouterModule]` to the `@NgModule()` where your are using `routerLink`

It should be `routerLink` instead of `routerlink`.
Directive selectors are case sensitive (component templates in general are case sensitive)

Comment: RouterModule is added to the module. Its working within the MenuComponent outside the router-outlet just next to it but not within the components rendered inside the router-outlet. Everything right now is within app.module.ts.

Comment: It should be `routerLink` instead of `routerlink`